# Задать формат даты

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Имеется:

1) в БД (sqlite, тип полей - TEXT)

- 01.04.2020
- 15.04.2020

2) в коде asp.net mvc:

- @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Date)
- @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Bid.Date)

3) На странице 2 поля: *04/01/2020 (1 апреля 2020)* ...
и *15.04.2020*

при сохранении, дата меняется на 04.01.2020

у меня были заданы даты также следующим образом:

- Дата: @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @type = "date", @style = "width: 165px" })
- Дата: @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.Bid.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @type = "date", @style = "width: 165px" })

отображается все равно *04/01/2020 (1 апреля 2020)* ...
и *15.04.2020*

знаю, что не рекомендуется стиль задавать прямо в теге, но я учусь, да и проще так (на текущий момент)

**Создал пост, чтобы узнать**
Что определяет формат отображения даты? Как принудительно сделать отображение в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ?

*Комментарий*
У меня есть основной проект, где таких проблем нет. В нем отображается все в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, но т.к. в дополнительном такие косяки, хотелось бы знать, как их исправить, если что

Comment: это связано с локализацией приложения здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560796/set-culture-in-an-asp-net-mvc-app приводятся примеры, в дальнейшем вам не нужно выставлять маску в полях так как это уже предусмотрено

Comment: я находил похожие посты здесь. У меня задана культура при помощи
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture ="ru-RU" />
  </system.web>

поскольку это не изменило ровным счетом ничего, решил задать вопрос

Comment: ну как видите это не совсем то что нужно, в том посте описано подругому, а именно сделать свой роутинг с принудительным установлением локали